# Serialize Doctrine Paginator for Caching purposes

Tags: php, symfony, caching, doctrine-orm, pagination

So I had a complex Entity with a few sub-entities managed by OneToManys and ManyToManys.

Using the basic `setMaxResults()` and `setFirstResult()` methods were returning less than the desired number of results (when executing the runnable query, I get back my set limit of results, but there are repeat records which Doctrine then trims down and returns the unique records only). Looking through stackoverflow I came across the `Paginator` Doctrine Tool class.

The issue that I have, is that I need to cache the results. I use Doctrine's ApcCache interface, but when I try to save it to the cache, I get back `Exception: Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed`.  But the Paginator class doesn't seem to allow me to acquire the the results of the query (just the 10). And obviously when I do this:

```
$results = new Paginator($query, $fetchJoin = true);
return $results->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Im back to my original problem of getting less than my desired limit of records (as now we're going back to the original method of getting results)

I just want the array of results, so I may serialize and cache it. What's the best approach to doing that?

Thanks

---

**EDIT**

Right now, I am adding a foreach loop and collecting the records into an array. Which seems to work, but I wonder if theres a better way of handling this, than adding another loop in each of my Repository methods...

```
        $results = new Paginator($query, $fetchJoin = true);

        $return = [];
        foreach($results as $result) {
            $return[] = $result;
        }

        $cache->save($cacheKey, $return, 300);

        return $return;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `iterator_to_array()`, Doctrine Paginator implements the traversable interface http://php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-to-array.php

Comment: Whoa! That's an awesome function :D Totally can't wait to jump back into my code and refactor my (applicable) loops with this.   The big problem I got with the Paginator class is it seems to acquire ALL of the records in the DB and THEN applies the logic of acquiring just the records I want out of the loop. I had a sub-entity set to `EAGER` and my query count went completely bananas every page load haha